# Can we create a modulated GLaDOS sounding voice using JS SpeechSynthesis?

Tags: javascript, html, text-to-speech, speech-synthesis

**Using the built in [W3 SpeechSynthesis API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/speech-api/raw-file/tip/webspeechapi.html#speechsynthesisevent), is it possible to create a modulated voice like [that of GLaDOS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ccHI8BPUkT4) with JavaScript?**

The code that I currently have (below) `split()`s the phrase to be synthesized into individual words, each to be uttered at a randomly determined pitch, in an attempt to create the desired effect.
There's too long a rest between the words uttered and the modulation is not satisfactory.

```js
if ('speechSynthesis' in window) {
    var speechSynthesis = window.speechSynthesis;
    speechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged = function () {
        console.log(speechSynthesis)
        var phrase = "Hello, I am GLaDOS";
        var parts = phrase.split(" ");
        for(var i in parts){
            var word = parts[i];
            var text = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(word);
            text.voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices[2]; //English Female Voice
            text.rate=1.2;
            text.pitch = Math.random()*.5+1.50;
            speechSynthesis.speak(text);
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** GLaDOS is *"[a fictional artificially intelligent computer system from the video game series Portal.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GLaDOS)"*

Comment: This isn't really a coding problem until you figure out the effects used.  Then you can figure out how to concrete implement them with the Web Audio API.

Comment: Unfortunately, most of what made GLaDOS interesting was done by the incredible actress (Ellen McLain). She was responsible for the pitch shifts, the choice of timing and inflection of words, et cetera. VALVe just went ahead and added various filters and gates to it, afterward. Her performance can't really be recreated in an algorithmic manner, without some machine-learning software trained on GLaDOS' lines. You could do that in JS, but that's way beyond the scope of an SO question.

Answer (score 3):

## Auto-Tune

This answer is mostly opinion, offered in good faith in an attempt to be helpful.

Unfortunately, I believe, the effect on GLaDOS's voice would have to be achieved in what Hollywood would call "[Post-Production](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-production)" *i.e.* it would have to be an after effect; the voice would need to be processed after it is uttered.

Adjusting the pitch and/or rate will always only affect the output of the entire utterance, the result of which appears to be set in stone once [`SpeechSynthesis.speak()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis/speak) is called.
Your idea to split the utterance into words, and have each word output with randomized pitches and rates is clever, and that may be as close as we can get without Post-Processing.

By the way: I have no idea if we can apply Post-Processing to the utterances, and suspect that if it is at all possible, it would require some form of browser *extension/plugin*.

**However**, several of the voices (I strongly suspect the availability of voices is subject to change in a relatively unpredictable way) can be forced to effectively [Auto-Tune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto-Tune) if the pitch and rate are set *just right* (dependant on the voice).

With that said, I can't offer you anything beyond the standard interface.
But I noticed several issues with your posted code example that should be addressed if you plan to experiment.

In particular, your code:

> `text.voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices[2];`

will not select the third available voice. If you try changing the index value, you'll note that the voice doesn't change, because `window.speechSynthesis.getVoices` returns the function not the return of the function.
You could do:

```
text.voice = speechSynthesis.getVoices()[2];
```

but it is a bit presumptuous.

[`SpeechSynthesis.getVoices()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis/getVoices)

> ... returns a list of [`SpeechSynthesisVoice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisVoice) objects representing all the available voices on the current device.

and (in Chrome and Edge†) [`SpeechSynthesis.onvoiceschanged`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis/onvoiceschanged)

> ... will run when the list of `SpeechSynthesisVoice` objects that would be returned by the `SpeechSynthesis.getVoices()` method has changed (when the `voiceschanged` event fires.)
>
> This may occur when speech synthesis is being done on the server-side and the voices list is being determined asynchronously, or when client-side voices are installed/uninstalled while a speech synthesis application is running.

and as such, the triggering of which **could**† be used to initiate compilation of the list of voices, which can **then** be accessed like:

```
var voices = SpeechSynthesis.getVoices();
utterance.voice = voices[ 2 ];
```

> **†** Note that Firefox doesn't support it at present, and will just return a list of voices when `SpeechSynthesis.getVoices()` is fired. With Chrome however, you have to wait for the event to fire before populating the list ...

### *"Welcome to the aperture science computer aided enrichment center"*

Although the code below won't provide an Auto-Tuned GLaDOS voice *magically*, it will provide an easier way to experiment with the possibilities, and demonstrates how *properly* to access the available voices.

## Inserted Update (Jan 6, 2019):

At the time of writing the code below, Google's default voice was female and the effect was, because of that, better than may now be heard. These APIs and their related resources and services are subject to change.

Also note that `SpeechSynthesis.speak()` in Chrome [since v70](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5687444770914304) (other browsers may follow) will "immediately fire an error if the document has not received user activation".

#### End update.

```js
if ( window.hasOwnProperty( "speechSynthesis" ) ) {
  var opt, voices, utterance;
  const speechSynth = window.speechSynthesis,
        form = document.querySelector( "form" ),
        playSample = () => {
          if ( speechSynth.speaking ) {
            speechSynth.cancel();
            // doesn't work as expected with default voice on Chrome on Windows
          }
          utterance = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance( form.sample.value );
          utterance.voice = voices[ form.voice.selectedIndex ];
          utterance.volume = form.volume.valueAsNumber * 0.01;
          utterance.pitch = form.pitch.valueAsNumber * 0.01;
          utterance.rate = form.rate.valueAsNumber * 0.01;
          speechSynth.speak( utterance );
        },
        init = () => {
          if ( !voices ) { // fixes triple trigger weirdness
            voices = speechSynth.getVoices();
            voices.forEach( ( v ) => {
              opt = document.createElement( "option" );
              opt.textContent = v.name;
              if ( v.name === "Google US English" ) {
                opt.selected = true;
                form.rate.value = 65;
              }
              form.voice.appendChild( opt );
            } );
            form.addEventListener( "input", playSample, false );
            form.play.addEventListener( "click", playSample, false );
            playSample();
          }
        };
  if ( speechSynth.onvoiceschanged !== undefined ) {
    // Only Chrome and Edge at time of posting
    speechSynth.onvoiceschanged = init;
  } else {
    init();
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 50vh;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
label {
  display: block;
}
input {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
[name=sample] {
  width: 90vw;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
[name=play] {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name="sample" type="text" value="Hello. And again, welcome to the aperture science computer aided enrichment center. We hope your brief detention in the relaxation vault has been a pleasant one.">
  <div><select name="voice"></select></div>
  <label>Volume: <input name="volume" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="50"></label>
  <label>Pitch: <input name="pitch" type="range" min="0" max="200" value="100"></label>
  <label>Rate: <input name="rate" type="range" min="1" max="1000" value="100"></label>
  <input name="play" type="button" value="Play it again Sam">
</form>
```

P.S. Although functioning perfectly whilst creating/editing the snippet, I have noticed since publishing that the results are glitchy.
I suspect this is a browser issue (experimental technology) as no errors are logged, and no code has changed.
**On further examination**, I noticed that the *acceptable* ranges for `rate` and `pitch` differ for different `voice`s.
*e.g.* "`Google US English`" won't play at a higher `rate` than `2`, whereas "`Microsoft Anna - English (United States)`" will play at the full `rate` of `10`.

Both [Google developer docs](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/01/Web-apps-that-talk-Introduction-to-the-Speech-Synthesis-API#basics) and [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesisUtterance/rate) agree that `rate`'s range should be from `0.1` to `10`, but MDN states:

> A float representing the rate value. It can range between `0.1` (lowest) and `10` (highest), with `1` being the default pitch for the current platform or voice, which should correspond to a normal speaking rate. ...

and then goes on to state:

> **Some speech synthesis engines or voices may constrain the minimum and maximum rates further. ...**

There seem to be many little niggles with this fairly new API that, until it is fully standard, will require case by case targeted solutions.

Comment: Lots of research and effort into an answer, but unfortunately the question is too broad for SO.

Comment: @AndrewLi - I think it's a valid question; "how, using a language, can an effect be achieved?" Even if the answer is "it can't" the question is still valid; no?